# Pentaho CDE reset parameter

Tags: parameters, datatable, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a data table component and seven  multiple selectors related to it. And i want to reset all selectors to default value with a reset button. 
My data source is SQL database, so i don't have a select "All" option in these selector. Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: Just add a button or <p> inside a HTML component and specify href as href="" this will reload your dashboard with default settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues you need to solve:

1. Adding default values for the selectors
2. Adding a button that resets these selectors to their default value

For **1** I would go for something like this:

- Set the SQL query for the selectors datasource like this:

  `SELECT '%' FROM [ANY TABLE] UNION [YOUR EXISTING QUERY]`

  This way you will also have the value `%` as a possible option. This will be your default value, but your DataTable query will have to use `LIKE ${YOUR_PARAMETER}` in the `WHERE` clause for it to work.

Now for **2** you need some preparation to make things work:

- Make your select components **listen** to the same parameter they are setting. This way changing a parameter will also trigger the update of the select UI.
- Add a Script component so you can write the function to reset the parameters in it. This way, you can call this function on the event of a button press.
- The final trick is just to add a button which will trigger this function. You can use plain old HTML+JS syntax.

The function + HTML button would be something like this:

```js
function resetParameters() {
  // The names of the parameters to be reset
  var parameters = [
    'param1',
    'param2',
    ...
  ];

  // Iterate them
  parameters.each(function(param) {
    // Fire the change to the default value. 
    // The selects are listening for this and will change 
    // the selected item accordingly
    Dashboards.fireChange(param, '%');
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="resetParameters()">Reset</button>
```

I haven't tried but it should do the trick!