# How to add a "select all" option to select component in CDE?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a select component on my dashboard and i want to add a "select all" option to be a default value of this selector. The data source for this select component is SQL. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: See my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474549/pentaho-cde-reset-parameter/37999391#37999391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add select all option as a default value i will explain you with an example.

consider i have two distinct rows in one column(eg: Category is the column name and there are two rows in that column "Billable","Non-Billable") selecting either of this two is possible or selecting both using multiselect can also be done.suppose if i want to add "All Category" as third row in Category column and use that to select both.below is the procedure and screen shot.

In Components Panel:

under Generic select custom Parameter
Name : Param1
javascript code : "All Category"
rest default values

under Selects select  selectmulti Component

Name: select1
Parameter: Param1
Listeners: Param1
Datasource: Billability_query1(location where sql query to select component is wriiten)
Htmlobject: place holder to display select component.
rest all default values

Datasource Panel:

under Sql queries select sqlover sql jdbc

Query:

Select 'All Category' as Category from pentaho_output_report
UNION
Select Category from pentaho_output_report;

Parameters: Param1

[Click here for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXnOd.jpg)

hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A second solution :

If you have a selector which allow you to choose the Division (for example)

By default, the query of the selector will be something like :

```
with member [Measures].[Name] as '[Division].CurrentMember.UniqueName' select TopCount( filter({Descendants([Division].[All Divisions] ,[Division].[Division])}, not isempty(([Division].CurrentMember)) ) , 50) on ROWS, 
 {[Measures].[Name]} on Columns 
 from YOUR_SOURCE
```

You can adapt this by :

```
with member [Measures].[Name] as '[Division].CurrentMember.UniqueName' select  {Descendants([Division].[All Divisions])}  on ROWS, 
 {[Measures].[Name]} on Columns 
 from YOUR_SOURCE
```

This way, the first item will be "All Division" and the others will follow.
Then you can put in the chart parameter "[Division].[All Division]" to specify that you want the first one as parameter

Hope this will help